# Error: glob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'root_dir'

Tags: python-3.x, glob

I'm running a python script

```
if len(glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx", root_dir=".")) > 0:
  print('Found') 
else:
  print("Enter a valid path.")
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: glob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'root_dir'
```

I'm using Python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

The glob.glob gained the root_dir and dir_fd parameters in Python 3.10.

See [Package description](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

You could do something like this :

```
def search_xlsx(rootdir):
    file_list = []
    for root, directories, file in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in file:
            if(file.endswith(".xlsx")):
                file_list.append(file)
    return file_list
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it was something in Python 3.10